# Configure activemq to be transactional

Tags: java, spring, configuration, activemq-classic, spring-jms

It´s more of a conceptual question: I currently have a working activemq queue which is consumed by a Java Spring application. Now I want the queue not to permanently delete the messages until the Java app tells it the message has been correctly saved in DB.  After reading documentation I get I have to do it transactional and usa the commit() / rollback() methods. Correct me if I'm wrong here.

My problem comes with every example I find over the internet telling me to configure the app to work this or that way, but my nose tells me I should instead be setting up the queue itself to work the way I want. And I can't find the way to do it.

Otherwise, is the queue just working in different ways depending on how the consumer application is configured to work? What am I getting wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest explicit acknowledgement via Message.acknowledge().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue it self is not aware of any transactional system but you can pass the 1st parameter boolean to true to create a transactional session but i propose the INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE when creating a session because you can manage messages one by one. Can be set on spring jms `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`    .

`ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE`
And calling this method to ack a message, unless the method is not called the message is considered as dispatched but not ack.

```
ActiveMQTextMessage.acknowledge();
```

**UPDATE:**

`ActiveMQSession.INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE` can be used like this :

```
onMessage(ActiveMQTextMessage message)
try {
    do some stuff in the database
    jdbc.commit(); (unless auto-commit is enabled on the JDBC)
    message.acknowledge();
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

> There are 2 kinds of transaction support in ActiveMQ.
>   JMS transactions - the commit() / rollback() methods on a Session (which is like doing commit() / rollback() on a JDBC connection)
>   XA Transactions - where the XASession acts as an XAResource by communicating with the Message Broker, rather like a JDBC Connection takes place in an XA transaction by communicating with the database.

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-transactions-work.html

> Should I use XA transactions (two phase commit?)
>   A common use of JMS is to consume messages from a queue or topic, process them using a database or EJB, then acknowledge / commit the message.
>   If you are using more than one resource; e.g. reading a JMS message and writing to a database, you really should use XA - its purpose is to provide atomic transactions for multiple transactional resources. For example there is a small window from when you complete updating the database and your changes are committed up to the point at which you commit/acknowledge the message; if there is a network/hardware/process failure inside that window, the message will be redelivered and you may end up processing duplicates.

http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-xa.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Hassen. Then, if the consumer dies before saving the message in DB, the message is lost? There's no way of avoiding this? I was trying to follow [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702533/configure-activemq-to-be-transactional) but found the same problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Just found XA, by the way. Would that solve my problem?

Comment: yeah too, take a look at my update, if you are not comfortable with transactions i think INDIVIDUAL_ACKNOWLEDGE  fits your requirements

Comment: if the consumer dies before saving the message in DB, the message is  re-delivered when the consumer reconnect if the ActiveMQTextMessage.acknowledge(); method was not called, as i said As long as this method is not called for the broker this message is not acknowledged and will be re-delivered later